# MySql unexpected query result

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have such a tables `offers` and `offer_operating_systems` related by `offer_id`. I made two queris and from my understanding they should return same result, but they don't

Query 1:

```
select
  count(*)
from
  `offers`
where
  (
     select count(*)
     from `offer_operating_systems`
     where
         `offer_operating_systems`.`offer_id` = `offers`.`id`
       and
        `operating_system` = 'android'
) = 1
order by `id` asc
```

Query 2:

```
select
  count(*)
from offer_operating_systems
where
  operating_system = 'android'
order by `id` asc
```

Can someone explain to me why the results are not the same? Thanks!

**EDITED**

`operating_system`column is unique so each offer can have only one record with `adnroid`

**Table structures**

```
CREATE TABLE `offers` (
                          `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                          `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
                          `type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                          `url` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
                          `status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
                          `api_created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                          `api_updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                          `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                          `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                          KEY `offers_status_index` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=423 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci


CREATE TABLE `offer_operating_systems` (
                                           `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                           `offer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
                                           `operating_system` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
                                           `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                                           `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                                           PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                                           UNIQUE KEY `offer_operating_systems_offer_id_operating_system_unique` (`offer_id`,`operating_system`),
                                           KEY `offer_operating_systems_offer_id_foreign` (`offer_id`), 
                                           CONSTRAINT `offer_operating_systems_offer_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`offer_id`) REFERENCES `offers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=728 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: order by `id` asc is completely irrelevant as both queries are giving to aggregate over complete table and give a single row (count)

Comment: Why do you think both query do the same ?  Query 1 uses offers and offer_operating_systems corelated and Query 2 ony table offer_operating_systems ...

Comment: With Query 1 you say *"Count all offers where the offer has **one** android operating system"* ... With Query 2 you say *"Count all android operating systems "*  .. Also @MadhurBhaiya is right about he order it is senseless on both queries as the result is always one record to begin with also it does not matter if you `count(1, 1, 2)` or `count(2, 1, 1)` it results into the same value

Comment: but if `operating_system` is a unique column is it not the same "Count all offers where the offer has android operating systems " and "Count all android operating systems" ?

Comment: *"but if operating_system is a unique column"* SQL is a declarative language, meaning you ask the RDMS what you want to how not want to how to get it, table structures/unique keys can change the meaning of these SQL queries, so i am "guessing" what these SQL queries most likely means without knowing tables structures..

Comment: ... with other words, post results off `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>`, for every table involved in this question and maybe also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: *"Count all offers where the offer has android operating systems "*  Would be most likely this SQL  ---> `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM offers INNER JOIN offer_operating_systems ON offers.id = offer_operating_systems.offer_id WHERE offer_operating_systems.operating_system = 'android'`

Comment: I add a table structure to the original question. Also, I tried a query with join you provided above and it also has a different result. All 3 queries return a different results

Comment: Create a fiddle with sample data to demonstrate the differences in the results.

Comment: hmm, while creating the fiddle I use first 100 offers and all 3 queries returning same results, so I assume that I have corrupted data somewhere (maybe some values are not unique by some reason), I need to  troubleshoot it

Comment: okay, I found that some offer has 2 records with `andorid` for some reason but I do not understand how it's possible as I have `UNIQUE KEY`,  I think I can close this question